# split 3 data frames evenly using the unique id

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have three tables: `upload`, `pap1`, `pap2`) each table has 50 column and 150 thousands of rows, I want to split the three [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s into  matched multiple dataframes( where each subset has max 1000 rows) using the unique primary key,
 for example, `subset_upload1` must have the same ID'S in `subset_pap1` and `subset_pap2` and so on...

```
 employee_id<-c(1,2,3)
 employee <- c('John','Peter ','Jolie')
 salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
 startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

 upload<- data.frame(employee_id,employee, salary, startdate)

 employee_id<-c(1,2,3)
 line_1<-c('address1','address2','address3')
 line_2<-c('address1','address2','address3')
 postcode<-c('postcode1','postcode2','postcode')

 pap1<-data.frame(employee_id,line_1,line_2,postcode)


 age<-c(57,43,23)
 Height<-c(150,170,190)
 gender<-c('M','M','F')
 enddate<-as.Date(c('2020-11-1','2020-3-25','2020-3-14'))

 pap2<-data.frame(employee_id,age,Height,gender,enddate)
```

the outcome I am hoping to is:

```
    subupload1<-data.frame(employee_id =1,employee = "John",salary=21000,startdate=as.Date('2010-11-1'))
   subpap1_1<-data.frame(employee_id=1,line_1='address1',line_2='address1',postcode='postcode1')
         subpap2_1<-data.frame(age=57,Height=150,gender='M',enddate=as.Date('202011-1'))
```

Comment: it would help if you had an example of your dataframe dput(head(mydataframe))). When you say you have 3 tables do you mean data.frames, or these are tables that have to be converted to dataframe type first? It is a bit unclear to me but this could be only me.

Comment: It seems like a task suited for the `split` function. If you can't provide an example, have a look at: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/split

Comment: i added an example @DimitriosZacharatos, Sorry i am new to R

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem in order to help and get some points. No need to be sorry

Comment: it looks to me that this is a subsetting problem

Comment: I added a solution but I am still not sure if this is what you want. Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `while` loop to randomly sample `n` unique id's and subset them from 3 dataframes respectively to create new dataframe.

```
n <- 1 #Number of unique primary key in one dataframe
remaining_ids <- unique(upload$employee_id)
counter <- 1

while(length(remaining_ids) > n) {
   ids <- sample(remaining_ids, n)
   assign(paste0("subupload_", counter), subset(upload, employee_id %in% ids))
   assign(paste0("subpap1_", counter), subset(pap1, employee_id %in% ids))
   assign(paste0("subpap2_", counter), subset(pap2, employee_id %in% ids))
   counter <- counter + 1
   remaining_ids <- setdiff(remaining_ids, ids)
}

assign(paste0("subupload_", counter),subset(upload, employee_id %in% remaining_ids))
assign(paste0("subpap1_", counter), subset(pap1, employee_id %in% remaining_ids))
assign(paste0("subpap2_", counter), subset(pap2, employee_id %in% remaining_ids))
```

However, try to use lists to better handle/manage data instead of polluting your global environment with lots of objects.

---

If we want to write all these as csv we can use `write.csv` instead of `assign` like :

```
while(length(remaining_ids) > n) {
  ids <- sample(remaining_ids, n)
  write.csv(subset(upload, employee_id %in% ids), paste0("subupload_", counter, ".csv"))
  write.csv(subset(pap1, employee_id %in% ids), paste0("subpap1_", counter, ".csv"))
  write.csv(subset(pap2, employee_id %in% ids), paste0("subpap2_", counter, ".csv"))
  counter <- counter + 1
  remaining_ids <- setdiff(remaining_ids, ids)
}
write.csv(subset(upload, employee_id %in% remaining_ids), paste0("subupload_", counter, ".csv"))
write.csv(subset(pap1, employee_id %in% remaining_ids), paste0("subpap1_", counter, ".csv"))
write.csv(subset(pap2, employee_id %in% remaining_ids), paste0("subpap2_", counter, ".csv"))
```

Comment: thank you @Ronak   if I run your code then I will end up with 150000 subtables for each data frame (150000 unique employees), I want each sub-table to have max 1000 employees

Comment: @ryan Change the first line from `n <- 1` to `n <- 1000`.

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you so much for your help @Ronak, last question is there a way to save them all asCSV files

Comment: @ryan you could replace `assign` with `write.csv`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
upload<-data.frame(employee_id=c(1,2,3),
                   employee=c('John','Peter','Jolie'),
                   salary=c(21000,23400,26800),
                   startdate=as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')))

pap1<-data.frame(employee_id=c(1,2,3),
                 line_1=c('address1','address2','address3'),
                 line_2=c('address1','address2','address3'),
                 postcode=c('postcode1','postcode2','postcode'))

pap2<-data.frame(employee_id=c(1,2,3),
                 age=c(57,43,23),
                 Height=c(150,170,190),
                 gender=c('M','M','F'),
                 enddate=as.Date(c('2020-11-1','2020-3-25','2020-3-14')))

subupload1<-data.frame(employee_id=1,employee = "John",salary=21000,startdate=as.Date('2010-11-1'))
subpap1<-data.frame(employee_id=1,line_1='address1',line_2='address1',postcode='postcode1')
subpap2<-data.frame(employee_id=1,age=57,Height=150,gender='M',enddate=as.Date('2020-11-1'))

upload[upload$employee_id%in%1,]
upload[upload$employee_id%in%1:2,]
upload[upload$employee_id%in%1:3,]



upload<-upload[order(upload$employee_id),]
pap1<-pap1[order(pap1$employee_id),]
pap2<-pap2[order(pap2$employee_id),]


upload<-data.frame(employee_id=1:150000,
                   employee=sample(c('John','Peter','Jolie'),150000,replace=TRUE),
                   salary=sample(c(21000,23400,26800),150000,replace=TRUE),
                   startdate=sample(as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')),150000,replace=TRUE))

split_setting<-c()
for(i in 1:(150000/1000))
  split_setting<-c(split_setting,rep(i,1000))

result<-split(upload,split_setting)

result$`1`
nrow(result$`1`)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this but as I mentioned in my original question I have three tables each table has 150,000 rows which are unique and employee and I need each table to be split it into multiple table with at least with maximum 1000 employing each one following the same logic in my example, so subuplaod is will have 1000employeeswhom are the same in subpap1-1 and subpap2-1 and subupload2 will have the second time 1000 employees whom ar on subpap1-1 and subpap2-1 and so on

Comment: no worries, do you actually need a way to do a lot of splits in an automatic way?

Comment: I am missing something

Comment: exactly, because have to run it every day

Comment: each table will be split into 150 tables with 1000 row in each, and subtable  from the upload must have the same employeeids in the other tow subtables

Comment: I think I understand better now. The next question is after you split them how do you want to store them as (1) dataframes with different names or (2) as a list containing a lot of dataframes?

Comment: I want to store them as data frames with different names, so I can use them for farther analysis